# Android: play multiple mp3s simultaneously, with precise sync and independent volume control

Tags: android, audio, media-player

I want to create an Android app that plays multiple mp3s simultaneously, with precise sync (less than 1/10 of a second off) and independent volume control. Size of each mp3 could be over 1MB, run time up to several minutes.  My understanding is that MediaPlayer will not do the precise sync, and SoundPool can't handle files over 1MB or 5 seconds run time. I am experimenting with [superpowered](http://superpowered.com) and may end up using that, but I'm wondering if there's anything simpler, given that I don't need any processing (reverb, flange, etc.), which is superpowered's focus.

Also ran across the YouTube video on Android high-performance audio, from Google I/O 2016. Wondering if anyone has any experience with this.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F2ZDp-eNrh4

Comment: Write your own audio engine. Or you can, as you mentioned, use  superpowered.

Answer (score 3):

Superpowered was originally made for my DJ app (DJ Player in the App Store), where precisely syncing multiple tracks is a requirement.

Therefore, syncing multiple mp3s and independent volume control is definitely possible and core to Superpowered. All you need is the SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer class for this.

The CrossExample project in the SDK has two players playing in sync.

The built-in audio features in Android are highly device and/or build dependent. You can't get a consistent feature set with those. In general, the audio features of Android are not stable. That's why you need a specialized audio library which does everything "inside" your application (so is not a "wrapper" around Android's audio features).

Comment: Can we get Beatgrid based on the beatgridStartMs parameter of any music file using Superpowered SDK?

Answer (score 0):

When you are playing compressed files (AAC, MP3, etc) on Android in most situations they are decoded in hardware to save power, except when the output goes to a USB audio interface. The hardware codec accepts data in big chunks (again, to save power). Since it's not possible to issue a command to start playing multiple streams at once, what will often be happening is that one stream will already send a chunk of compressed audio to hardware codec, and it will start playing, while others haven't yet sent their data.

You really need to decode these files in your app and mix the output to produce a single audio stream. Then you will guarantee the desired synchronization. The built-in mixing facilities are mostly intended to allow multiple apps to use the same sound output, they are not designed for multitrack mixing.

Comment: superpowered claims to support synchronized playback on Android:       "The SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer's play() method has a 'synchronised' flag. It will start playback synced to a master tempo and beatgrid you set in the process() method. An example can be found in the cross example project. (The example project is for iOS, but all Superpowered code is cross-platform)."    http://superpowered.com/synchronized-recording-and-playback-of-audio-cpu-requirements-time-stretching-x86-dsp-android-version-support-beat-detection

Comment: I'm not surprised because their framework has all the required components: compressed format decoders, resamplers, mixers, etc. so they can create a single mixed stream from multiple sources on their own. That's exactly the approach I've described.